# How can I extend a nested object with another nested object immutably?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a "base" object like this:

```
{
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 123
    },
    hello: 'world',
    something: {
      deeply: {
        nested: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then say I want to "extend" that nested object with another object, thereby "adding" properties to the base object, *but without mutably changing it*, and without also just recreating every object in the tree! It should be somewhat optimized by only recreating objects which need to be recreated, so only doing `{ ...x }` where it needs to be done because we are changing something...

So say I extend our base object with an "updates" object that looks like this:

```
{
  foo: {
    hello: 'earth',
    something: {
      deeply: {
        iAmNew: 32134
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The end result is obviously this:

```
{
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 123
    },
    hello: 'earth',
    something: {
      deeply: {
        nested: true,
        iAmNew: 32134
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it should not recreate the `{ baz: 123 }` object, because nothing changed there.

In my situation, I have a complex, deeply nested (up to eight levels deep) settings object. So if every time you changed a setting it recreated this whole object, that seems inefficient. It should just change the parts that change, while leaving the rest intact.

Can it be done easily?

```
export function extend(
  start,
  updates,
) {
  const end = { ...start }

  let node = end

  for (const i in updates) {
    const val = updates[i]
    if (val != null) {
      if (typeof val === 'object') {
      }
    }
  }

  return end
}
```

Comment: Presumably this object contains only primitives for values? What about arrays?

Comment: Also this looks like a Typescript question. It's not clear what the intended parameters are for that function. Would you pass in something like a path to the sub-object to be updated?

Comment: No the values can be arrays, strings, booleans, numbers, nulls, basically any JSON value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I assumed deepMerge (which you can do with lodash I think), would clone every property in the trees, which I would like to avoid if possible. That's the whole point of this question. Is that correct assumption?

Comment: If you extend object A to create B, and then modify A, should those modifications be visible in B?

Comment: @AndrewParks you will never mutably change these objects, so you will never directly modify A.

Comment: Did you try _validating_ that assumption? The proposed dupe has quite a few different answers.

Comment: At first glance it seems like you're looking for persistent data-structures. For example there's [immutable-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable) package which provide some of them

Comment: Home grown, type-safe implementation that does what you asked: https://tsplay.dev/mxkE1N

Comment: if `{ baz: 123 }` should disappear, what about `bar` or `nested: true` elements, should they have to disappear too ?

Answer (score -1):

This approach will create a shallow clone of the original, and add in extra properties.

```js
const a = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 123
    },
    hello: 'world',
    something: {
      deeply: {
        nested: true
      }
    }
  }
}

const updates = {
  foo: {
    hello: 'earth',
    something: {
      deeply: {
        iAmNew: 32134
      }
    }
  }
}

function f(a, b) {
  let c = {...a};
  Object.entries(b).forEach(([k,v])=>
    c[k] = !Object.hasOwn(c, k) || typeof v !== 'object' ? v : f(c[k],v)
  )
  return c;
}

console.log(f(a, updates));
console.log(a);
```